# Selectable values in query function in Google Sheets

Tags: function, google-sheets

I was creating a summary for my orders in Google Sheets and was able to make this.

```
=QUERY('2021'!A1:AA5000, "select D,G,
count(V) where V is not null and V ='Shipped' and G ='NAJ' and D ='January'
group by D,G
label count(V) 'Total Orders'")
```

I want to make V, G, and D values not to be hardcoded but selectable from a dropdown.
Being searching on the internet for half of the day with no help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`=QUERY('2021'!A1:AA5000, "select D,G, count(V) where V is not null and V ='"&X1&"' and G ='"&X2&"' and D ='"&X3&"' group by D,G label count(V) 'Total Orders'")`

Where `X1`, `X2` and `X3` are your cell references.

To get all months, try:

`=QUERY('2021'!A:AK, "select D,G, count(V) where V is not null and V ='Shipped' and G ='"&$D$4&"' and D "&if(E3=true,"is not null","='"&$D$3&"'")&" group by D,G label count(V) 'Total Orders'")`

[image]

Comment: Great. One more thing what if i want to add one more thing like D = ALL MONTH and it should show all the month.?

Comment: Perhaps `and D is not null` ?

Comment: Can you share a sample sheet? Difficult to know without seeing the context of the data.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QHIrfVfbGhd5Zk0i6NKEqy4rC7nvrmsNWqlE0VHqV7I/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sample sheet attached